# Do I need set both HttpHandler and HttpClient in GrpcChannelOptions?

Tags: .net-core, grpc, dotnet-httpclient

`GrpcChannelOptions` accepts both `HttpHandler` and `HttpClient`

`SocketsHttpHandler.EnableMultipleHttp2Connections` creates new HTTP/2 connections when needed.
And `HttpClient` internally creates new connections when it is required (as I understand).

```cs
        GrpcChannelOptions _options = new GrpcChannelOptions()
        {
            HttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true, // additional HTTP/2 connections are created by a channel when the concurrent stream limit is reached. 
                PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                KeepAlivePingDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40),
                KeepAlivePingTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
            },
            DisposeHttpClient = true,
            HttpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (HttpRequestMessage _, X509Certificate2? _, X509Chain? _, SslPolicyErrors _) =>
                {
                    return true;
                },
                UseProxy = false,
            })
            {
                DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0),
            }
        };
```

I have a singlton `GrpcChannel` creating with above option. is it ok to configure both fields as above?